# Автоматическая выгрузка каталога из таблицы excel в БД

Tags: php, mysql, excel

Вопрос довольно абстрактный, поэтому и не требует конкретного решения, буду рад если кто-то сможет навести меня на правильную мысль ;)

Есть сайт с каталогом товаров, товары группируются по категориям, т.е. каждая категория связаня с N-м количеством товаров. У Каждой категории и у каждого товара есть некоторый набор полей (наименование, описание и т.д. и т.п).

Стоит задача автоматизировать процесс заполнение каталога с большим количеством товаров и категорий на сайте, путём формирования таблицы в excel со всеми товарами и категориями и выгрузки этих данных на сайт.

Основная проблема, которую не удаётся решить - это привязка категорий и товаров на этапе формирования excel файла. Т.е. каким образом организовать структуру Excel-файла чтобы можно было связать категории и товары, как вариант, можно для каждой записи в отдельной ячейке вручную указывать какие-то идентификаторы, но такой вариант сильно усложняет задачу...

Comment: Почему именно `excel`? Почему не json, xml? Распарсить `excel` -  более трудоемкий процесс.

Comment: *каким образом организовать структуру Excel-файла чтобы можно было связать категории и товары* Структура файла должна быть плоской, одноуровневой. Идиотские красивости с раскрывающимися плюсиками и шапками во всю ширину - убрать нафиг. Если в категории 10 товаров - то у каждого в отдельной колонке прописана категория, полностью. И сохранить всё это во вменяемый CSV.

Comment: Andrey Mihalev, потому что задача сделать не разовую выгрузку, а сделать инструмент для быстрого заполнения каталога из сотен товаров для менеджеров, которые не знают что такое xml и json

Comment: @Akina, идея интересная, я тоже думал в этом направлении, только думаю не дублировать всю информацию о категории, а только её ID, Остальную информацию о категориях можно выгружать отдельно, но тогда остаётся проблема связи товаров и категории...

Comment: Вот нафига СОЗДАВАТЬ себе проблему? Байтов жалко? так их всё одно никто не купит... зато наличие полной информации в каждой записи позволит сразу нормально привязывать её куда нужно. Импортируешь CSV во временную таблицу, а потом раскидываешь запросами по связанным рабочим таблицам.

Comment: *задача .. для менеджеров, которые не знают что такое xml и json* - а им и не нужно. Программа сама всё сделает. Ты, когда, скажем, фильм на компе смотришь, дофига знаешь про AVI?

Comment: В Экселе есть страницы, вполне можно их использовать как аналог таблиц в БД если на то уж пошло.

Comment: Может каждый лист excel - отдельная категория товаров? Если, конечно товары не пересекаются по ним.

Comment: "привязка категорий и товаров на этапе формирования excel файла" Что имеется в виду? Уже есть информация какой товар в какой категории или на этапе заполнения указывается категория?

Comment: @becouse, как раз задача в том, чтобы придумать максимально простой способ импортировать каталог с категориями и товарами на сайт, у менеджера изначально есть вся информация о товарах и категориях, он знает какие товары к каким категориям относятся, ему нужно формировать excel файл со всей этой информацией, чтобы потом в пару кликов импортировать его на сайт

Comment: Для этого нужно чтобы менеджер понимал процесс импорта товаров через Excel на сайт, и смог предоставить шаблон, пример, используя который вы сможете произвести генерацию и создать конечный Excel файл для него/неё. У разных сайтов - разные способы и представления структур данных, так что одно решение на всё вряд ли получится, а если и получится, то может быть недостаточно точным.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, данный функционал будет дополнением к одному модулю, устанавливаемому на некий движок, так что список всех полей известен заранее и меняться не будут, а если что-то изменится то я сразу внесу правки в шаблон Excel-выгрузки

Comment: Кто-нибудь напишите развёрнутый ответ, отдам 50 рейтинга, а то жалко, пропадает :)

Comment: Я бы разработал стандарт `excel`, для начала. А уже потом бы говорил об импорте через сайт. И это абсолютно разные задачи. А что вы хотите увидеть в развёрнутом ответе? И да, вы бы уточнили, как менеджеру удобно заполнять этот документ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый банальный способ - это трансформировать данные в CSV, и работать уже с CSV файлом.

Например для MySQL :

```
SELECT id, name, email INTO OUTFILE 'export.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' FROM members;
```

И никто тебе не запрещает создать некий bash скрипт, который будет заходить на сервер, забирать .tar.gz файл в котором дампы нескольких CSV файлов таких как category.csv, products.csv и т.п.

```
load data local infile '/export.csv' 
replace 
into table test.members 
columns terminated by ',' 
enclosed by '"' 
lines terminated by '\n';
```